Use spack installed packages on older OS / ship glibc with spack repository?
We want to use Spack to distribute software among a heterogeneous Linux landscape.
When installing a package, Spack uses the local version of glibc (from Ubuntu 22).
Running the installed package on another machine with Ubuntu 18, it throws the error "version `GLIBC_2.34' not found" since this software in turn uses the local glibc 2.27.
I tried to somehow also ship the glibc version 2.35 with all other packages in the Spack repository.
But I don't know how to do this, or whether this is possible at all...

Note that you can also get answers on slack.spack.io, where the maintainers would be happy to talk about this.

We're working on enabling an entirely spack-built glibc (see #42082) so that you could target an older OS from a newer one, but in the meantime what you can do is build on the oldest Linux that you want to install on, and then run on the old and new Linux.
As of v0.22.0, Each build is annotated with the libc it depends on, and that annotation is used to determine compatibility when installing on other linux versions. See the v0.22.0 release notes for details on how libc compatibility is handled.
